# Accessing a folder through use of java?

Tags: java, image, directory

my friend and i are making a game for our computer science class. It's only our second semester. What we are doing is a game that's like Pokemon, and for all 151 Pokemon, they have four images (we are not changing it i realize that there is probably easier ways to do this but we don't have time to change it).

What we have is inside of our program's folder we have a subfolder for images (to keep things organized). We need to access the images from this folder. For example, one of the images is named "Bulbasaur_A.PNG". We know how to access the image through a string but how do we get to the 'images' folder?

Comment: @αƞjiβ No, the OP knows the image filename but not how to access the folder; this is possibly a duplicate, but of a different post.

Comment: Something like 'new File("images")' which will return a reference to the folder